# Humankind Vs Mankind

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I ran into the following context:

> - [humankind: human beings considered collectively (**used as a neutral alternative to “mankind”**)]

Also, I have read [another article](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-correct-humankind-or-mankind) about it.

But still I am confused! Do they mean that "mankind" is often used in a gender-specific way or this separation is just for being on the safe side?

Comment: You will find numerous sites that deal with your question if you google **humankind mankind**.

Comment: "Mankind" is _not_ gender-specific, but it is being avoided more and more in recent times, as you say, to be safe. Pedantry or well-meaning inclusion, you decide.

Comment: Then @Wehage does it mean that the usage of "mankind" in modern English sound weird or even sexist?

Comment: @A-friend To some people "mankind" sounds sexist. To many it is not sexist, and not gender specific at all. Sometimes you have the choice: Use the word "mankind", be accused of sexism, and apologize. Or use the word "mankind", be accused of sexism, and say STFU. Or use the word "humankind" and be accused of being "woke" or "a liberal" or "a commie" (Americans might do that), and say STFU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, "mankind" was never a gender-specific word. It was long accepted that "man" could refer to all "humans", not just males.

However, many changes in language and culture today are an attempt to address a previously perceived imbalance, and the word "humankind" is preferred by those who view "mankind" as promoting male dominance.

The word "womankind" has been coined to specifically mean women only, but the primary definition of "mankind" remains "human beings collectively".

Comment: Hmmm true ... but "humankind" also has "man" in it.

Comment: @AIQ Woman also has "man" in it.

Comment: Yes, ikr. A certain someone has coined the term "peoplekind" as an alternative to the "sexist" *humankind* and *mankind*. The use has been applauded by some.

Answer (score 1):

A short and the only correct explanation driven by logic would be: mankind includes male beings only, humankind both male ones and female ones. **Dot.** But...

First, it is vital to comprehend what language is. Language is a means of communication, it it created by *words* that *have their agreed meanings*. A dog cannot be a cat. In any way. Or a bear. They all are carnivoras, but they are not the same. Even a hybrid of a dog, cat and bear is something else. Something new. If somebody starts using words in a different way of meaning that is not agreed, (those) words stop being valid. They instantly forfeit their true (generally agreed) meaning. Another, analogous way is using words in the meaning that is already extinct. Which is concordantly the word mankind itself.

The word ‘man’ is the root. The base. This is what human beings have generally in common.

You may view it like so: According to the Bible or many other expositions of various sources, man (male) was the first one of the higher species. Then there was a woman. Created, or perhaps evolved, for him so that he would not be alone, lonely. Thus that ‘wo’ was added, like a distinguishing (women could have been easily called man 2.0 or something like that).

To avoid confusion – chaos which would (and did) cause it – there was devised a new world which would represent both two sexes: ‘human’. Therefore humankind from racial sight is just correct. People is from the social sight.

The term mankind cannot any longer contain all members of our race since the meaning has shifted, evolved. Mankind is only able to mean ‘man kind’, a kind of males, all men. That is all. It could apply in the past times, the dark(er) days of humanity, where it was irationally believed that women were not actually people, equal to men, just an inferior group. Thus did they treat them that way... All of those people who believed this were inferior to us. Why should we follow their wrong, bad practice, to praise them, or learn about them in school? Were they good and bringing benefit to the whole? No. That is the true.

Whoever uses the word mankind to mean men and women together (humans) in this time and times to come, is either a sexist, diehard or blockhead. A lesser being not capable of thinking rationally via logic. Since, and I will tell you this, parity of sexes and races are the two pillars that are typical and utterly imperative for any advanced society. Over them, nothing stands. Neither conceitedness, neither law, nor feelings of anybody who would think they could opress with their bad assumptions. That is an axiom, an uncontestable fact.

Do you comprehend now what the words mankind and humankind mean and why they are not actually synonyms?

Answer (score -1):

If we must exclude the word man from mankind there is already a perfectly acceptable word for that.  That word is "Humanity".

Try it out.  "That's one small step for Man... One giant leap for Humanity."
Sounds much better than  "That's one small step for people... one giant leap for peoplekind" or "That's one small step for human... one giant leap for humankind"

Comment: Correct is: "That's one small step for a man". Because a man said it, Neil Armstrong, and he said it about himself, and it was a small step for this particular person. And if you replace "mankind" with "humanity" you totally destroy the quote, because you destroy the contrast between "man" and "mankind".